# C - fscanf() - Reading Data Into an Array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'm getting a strange error when reading my data into an array. My goal is to read a file that has a single column of numbers into an array, line-by-line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numArray = [20];
    int i = 0;

    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen("numbers", "r");

    while(!feof(infile))
    {
        fscanf(infile,"%d",&numArray[i]);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(infile);
    return 0; }
```

This is my compile error:

> sort_algorithms.c: In function ‘main’: sort_algorithms.c:6: error:
>   expected expression before ‘[’ token sort_algorithms.c:16: error:
>   subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

Comment: What's the error?  `int numArray = [20]` isn't valid syntax, you probably meant `int numArray[[20]`?  And perhaps most importantly, you've got a gaping security hole—what happens if the file contains more than 20 numbers in it?

Comment: nick_name: that's not how you declare an array....

Comment: Are you by chance a python programmer?

Comment: Yes, I'm a Python programmer!

Comment: What's wrong with int numArray = [20]?

Comment: For declaration: int numArray[20];    For initialization: int numArray[20] = {20}, and the [20] means an array with size 20, not the element.

Comment: array literals are enclosed between {}, not []. and it can't be used as free as in python, i.e. you can't assign it except on initialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the correct way to declare an array in c is like this:

```
int numArray[20];
```